# Getting all subcategories and their products

Tags: magento2, catalog, view

I tried to get on my parent categories all the subcategories and products for each subcategories.
This is my products.phtml

```
<?php
$subcats = $this->getCategoryList();
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php
    foreach ($subcats as $subcat) {
        if ($subcat->getIsActive()) {

            $subcat_url = $subcat->getUrl();
            $subcat_img = "";
            $placeholder_img = "/media/placeholder.png";

            ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6 sub-cat-tile">
                <a href="<?php echo $subcat_url; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $subcat->getImageUrl() ? $subcat_img : $placeholder_img; ?>">
                    <p><?php echo $subcat->getName(); ?></p>
                </a>
            </div>

            <?php
            $allcategoryproduct = $this->getProducts($subcat);
            foreach ($allcategoryproduct as $product){
                ?>
            <div class="col-sm-6 sub-cat-tile">
                <a href="<?php echo $subcat_url; ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $product>getImageUrl() ? $subcat_img : $placeholder_img; ?>">
                    <p><?php echo $product>getName(); ?></p>
                </a>
            </div>
                <?php

            } ?>
            <?php
        }
    } ?>
</div>
```

and here is my block view.php

```
<?php
namespace Name\Categorylist\Block\Category;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class View extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
{
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver, 
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry, 
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $image,    
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,  
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,    
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory  $categoryFactory,
        array $data = array()) 
    {   
        parent::__construct($context, $layerResolver, $registry, $categoryHelper,$data);
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->image = $image;
     }

    public function getCategoryList()
    {
      $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
      $collection = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
              ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
              ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
              ->addIdFilter($_category->getChildren());
      return $collection;

    }
    public function getCategoryThumbImage($imageName) {
    $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
                \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
            );
        return  $mediaDirectory.'catalog/category/'.$imageName;

    }


    public function getPlaceholderImage(){
        return $this->image->getPlaceholder('image');
    }

    public function getProducts($category)
    {
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

The result show me the subcategories, but I can't get the products.
The only way I have found to get an echo of the product is with

> $allcategoryproduct->getData();

but then it show only few informations and can't get the name / price etc...
I think I miss something to echo a collection but can't find what.

Thank you.

Comment: My module has this function github.com/magepow/magento2-categories follow this to solve your problem.